# In Microsoft Test Manager (MTM), how t bind parameters to input fields?

Tags: microsoft-test-manager, mtm

I have a problem that I cannot find the answer to on the Internet and yet seems like it should be very simple, which makes me think I am dong something consistently stupid:

During Test Runner, I cannot bind parameters.

I have:

Action:
1.Open apps  Expection result: app opens  
2.  Do @Num1 + @Num2  Expectation result: Blah

Parameters: 
Num1   Num2 
10     20
40     10
13     18

The input fields are in the following html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
</body>
</html>
```

(I have also tried using a website with two text input boxes, and it didn't work either.)

When I am binding the parameter values to the fields in the html doc, it is not binding.  If it binds, the arrow pointing to the current parameter should shift to a check mark and the arrow point to the next parameter value.  (Otherwise, the arrow just moves to the next parameter.)  I have only gotten it to bind once, and I have no idea how.  I have tried:

~click on first input field, Ctrl-V, Tab, Ctrl-V (get 10 in first field and 10 in second field)
~manually entering 10 and 20
~click on first input, Ctrl-V, Tab, click on 20 in Num2=20, Ctr-V 
~instead of using Tab, going out of  focus my stepping outside input field 1 and then inside input field 2
~other various combinations using Enter, left-click, Tab, Ctrl-V, typing

(I never used right-click in any of these)

When I go through the iterations, the parameter numbers (not the numbers in the input fields), do update on the left side of the page.

None of these showed any evidence of binding.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know MTM will **try** find a path to the input boxes you use and bind your parameters to them. However, if the HTML snippet you provided is your actual HTML, it might be that MTM is not able to do this and thus is unable to create a path to the input box for you.

I am not sure this will help, but I can imagine the MTM test runner is having a difficult time binding. So try this to make it easier for MTM to identify the 2 input boxes:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" id="text-1" />
    <input type="text" id="text-2" />
  </body>
</html>
```